# How to combine 2 observations of an experimental unit on different dates into one row

Tags: r, duplicates, rows

I am attempting to combine observations (rows) based on multiple dates.  In my study, I sampled recruits on each module side on specific dates.  However, on few occasions, I had to come back to specific module sides to complete my censuses on a different date.  What I want to do for these instances is add the number of recruits together and have the date be the date of the last observation.

I attempted to use spread(n2, key = Date, value = recruits) but this was not helpful in getting the data from 2 rows into 1.

Database:

```
n3 <- structure(list(`Module #` = c(114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 
114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 
114L), Side = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("N", "S", "T"
), class = "factor"), TimeStep = c(1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), Date = structure(c(NA, 
17389, 17398, 17482, 17601, NA, 17299, 17389, 17404, NA, 17601, 
17682, 17299, 17389, 17404, NA, 17601, NA), class = "Date"), 
    Site = structure(c(NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, NA), .Label = c("HAN", "WAI"), class = "factor"), 
    Treatment = c(NA, "CLO", "CLO", "CLO", "CLO", NA, "CLO", 
    "CLO", "CLO", NA, "CLO", "CLO", "CLO", "CLO", "CLO", NA, 
    "CLO", NA), recruits = c(0, 5, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 4, 1, 0, 2, 
    4, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0), Site_long = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("Hanauma Bay", "Waikiki"), class = "factor"), 
    Shelter = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("High", "Low"
    ), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

print(n3)
```

As mentioned above, I want to combine observations for module sides where observations on two separate dates occurred by summing the number of recruits for both observations and making the date for the combined data row to be the date of the latter observation.  Thanks for your input!

Comment: I think you can use `group_by` here. Can you please provide the expected output? I'm not sure which rows to combine. An explanation will be helpful.

Comment: yarnabrina The output I want is to have the rows that are measured on different dates for the same side combined but to preserve the date column with the Date being the date from the second or last observation.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
n3 %>%
  group_by(`Module #`, Side, Site, Treatment) %>%
  summarize(Date = max(Date),
            recruits = sum(recruits)) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 6 x 6
  `Module #` Side  Site  Treatment Date       recruits
       <int> <fct> <fct> <chr>     <date>        <dbl>
1        114 N     WAI   CLO       2018-03-11        9
2        114 N     NA    NA        NA                0
3        114 S     WAI   CLO       2018-05-31       12
4        114 S     NA    NA        NA                0
5        114 T     WAI   CLO       2018-03-11        5
6        114 T     NA    NA        NA                0
```

Comment: Jon Spring Terrific this works!  One other thing do you happen to know a way such that the metadata for rows 2, 4, and 6 are kept instead of made to be NA?

Comment: In particular for the Site, Treatment, and Date columns?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Your original data has rows where those are NA, and that is reflected in the summary. You could filter them out if you don't want them, but I don't think anything is being converted to NA that wasn't already.

Comment: I see what you mean.  Would it be possible to fill in those NAs in n3 by pulling Date, Site, and Treatment from rows with the same `Module #` and TimeStep?  The idea is that the vast majority of the time, I sampled all three sides (N, S, and T) on the same day.

Comment: To further clarify, these data are count data hence why I need recruit counts for all module, side, and TimeStep combinations

Comment: You might consider filtering out rows with `0` recruits upstream, which would eliminate these ones. Or you could do something like `group_by(`Module #`, Side, TimeStep) %>% tidyr::fill(Site, Treatment, Date)` to fill in missing values for those columns.

Comment: The 0s are important in this case because 0 recruits means nothing settled in that quarter which is important.  I tried out the code you last provided on the original dataset n3 and after the code you posted and the values for Site, Treatment, and Date are not filling.